# TEXStudio does not detect TeXLive2015

Tags: latex

Today I installed TeX Studio. But it doesn't detect my texlive 2015! When I start TeX Studio, the message pops up:

```
there was no latex distribution found [...]
```

The path to my texlive 2015 is `~/.local/texlive`

`lualatex` in terminal results:

```
~/.local/texlive$ lualatex
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
 restricted \write18 enabled.
```

I wasn't able to set up TeX Studio manually.
So I'm hoping for an automatic setup when TeX Studio detects my texlive2105!

Maybe it doesn't detect it because it's in a hidden folder?

Comment: Upgrade to Wily and install `texlive-full (2015.20150625-1ubuntu1)`

Comment: how do I install texlive-full?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

Comment: how do I make sure do uninstall the old texlive? I installed it using the install-tl.tar + this command: TEXLIVE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/.local/texlive install-tl-*/install-tl        and also this command: echo export PATH=\"$(echo ~/.local/texlive/*/bin/*):\$PATH\" >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: can I just delete the folder /.local/texlive ?

Comment: If texlive is in `~/.local/texlive`, run `rm -r ~/.local/texlive`. But I have no idea, without seeing the installer, what the installer has done.

Comment: Ok, and remove the entry in your PATH. But that's not really necessary.

Comment: How can I open my "PATH"? Is it a file or what is it? (yup, totally new to Linux)

Comment: I will write another answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you asked for an alternative, `texlive-full` (`2015.20150625-1ubuntu1`) is in the Wily repositories.

1. Upgrade to Wily and install `texlive-full`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install texlive-full
   ```
2. Remove your manually installed version

   ```
   rm -r ~/.local/texlive
   ```

   and correct the PATH in your `.bashrc`:

   Because you have added the PATH with

   ```
   echo export PATH=\"$(echo ~/.local/texlive/*/bin/):\$PATH\" >> ~/.bashrc
   ```

   remove the entry with the command

   ```
   sed -i '/.local\/texlive/d' ~/.bashrc
   ```